Predicting a Noisy Target with High-dimensional Features
I am working on a regression problem with two sets of continuous features, $X_1$ and $X_2$ that I assume are useful for predicting a continuous target $y$ that is very noisy. By "noisy" I mean that a model that generalizes out-of-sample with an accuracy (e.g. correlation) of no more than 5% is good. One or both of $X_i$ are high-dimensional, $n \ll p$, and would be overparameterized for an unregularized OLS fit.
When I fit two models $f(X_1)$ and $f(X_2)$ to predict $y$, their predictions are similar and have correlated errors (residuals). Therefore they are less helpful when ensembled (e.g. bagged or boosted). However, we can assume there is information in $X_2$ that is useful for predicting $y$ in excess of what is in $X_1$ or different enough from what is in $X_1$.
What is a decent way to force $f(X_2)$ to be both correlated with $y$ and not correlated with the predictions $f(X_1)$?
I've been experimenting with regressing $X_2$ on $f(X_1)$; or PCA and ignoring the first few PCs (opposite of denoising); or partial least squares for latent variables and ignoring the first component; or adding a correlation penalty (e.g. cosine similarity) to the loss function. Is there a more principled approach?

What do you mean by saying that the features Xi are overparameterised?

Sorry, I’ve clarified the question. The high-dimensional dataset(s) /would/ mean an overparameterized setup if we were just doing old-school OLS.

The obvious and probably best solution here is to combine all predictors in one model. If that were impossible for some reason, instead of bagging or boosting you could try stacking the two models i.e. training a new model on the predictions from the first two models. A third (inferior) option would be to train the second model on the residuals of the first model.
If you have far more points than predictors, the model would benefit from some regularization, such as via the LASSO or elastic net. A random-forest is a different approach that can deal with this as well, but I doubt it would do better than a regularised regression if you have very few points.
